# How to sort rows by group in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Assume that I have a dataframe as below

```
Name Language
Tom  Japanese
Rose Japanese
……
Jack Chinese
Jack Japanese
Mike Japanese
Mike French
```

I want to leave the people who only speak Japanese but not speak others by checking the language column and get the output like:

```
Name Language
Tom  Japanese
Rose Japanese
```

Jack and Mike speak 2 languages so I only want to keep Tom and Rose.

Comment: `df.query('Language == "Japanese"')`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is called df. The following code will set the df equal to where the Language column equals Japanese.

```
df = df[df['Language'] == 'Japanese']
```